# Кавычки в названиях вилл и парков (вилла "Ла Гранж", парк "Ла Гранж")

Tags: кавычки

Вижу в СМИ, что вилла Ла Гранж (в Женеве) пишется без кавычек (как и парк Ла Гранж). Подскажите, как все же правильно? Мне казалось, что такие названия кавычатся (как парк "Сокольники", например). Или в данном случае кавычки действительно не нужны?

Answer (score 1):

Подобные названия берутся из географических названий и по принадлежности к фамилиям владельцев и пишутся без кавычек. Это имя собственное:

> словосочетание или предложение, предназначенное для выделения
> конкретного объекта из ряда однотипных объектов

Например, Ля Рошель мы будем писать без кавычек. Название графства будем писать без кавычек. Название виллы тоже.
А вот парк, гостиницу, даже если они и стилизованы под французский манер, следует писать в кавычках, так как это просто название по документам, которое можно просто изменить на новое.